# C# Copy datatable to new datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, sum, copy

I am about to create a chartview that will be populated from a datatable. The datatable looks like this:

[image]
EDIT:

This is how I am trying to use the code:

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();

            using (var da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Emner WHERE LastCallDato <> ('" + DBNull.Value.ToString() + "');", Varribles.ConString))
            {
                da.Fill(table);
            }


            IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));

            /*
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("26-07-2017 16:45", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Callback" });
            */

            string[] uniqueStatus = table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Status")).Distinct().ToArray();

            DataTable results = new DataTable();
            results.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            foreach (string status in uniqueStatus)
            {
                results.Columns.Add(status, typeof(int));
            }

            var groups = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = results.Rows.Add();
                newRow["Date"] = group.Key;
                var colGroups = group.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Status")).ToList();
                foreach (var colGroup in colGroups)
                {
                    newRow[colGroup.Key] = colGroup.Count();
                }
            }
```

I get an error saynig:

```
System.InvalidCastException: DBNull.Value cannot be converted to the type of 'System.DateTime'. Use another type that can be null
```

The error triggers on this line:

```
                var groups = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date).ToList();
```

Comment: Try this : DataTable filteredTable = table.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => (x.Field<DateTime>("dtDate") >= dateStart) && (x.Field<DateTime>("dtDate") < dateEnd)).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: It threw errors, and I it does only copy the row to another datatable

Answer (score 1):

You want a pivot table.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));

            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("26-07-2017 16:45", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Callback" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("26-07-2017 16:48", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Callback" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("26-07-2017 08:59", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Callback" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("28-07-2017 18:16", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Ingen Kontakt" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("26-07-2017 09:00", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Callback" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("26-07-2017 18:35", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Ja" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("26-07-2017 17:43", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Callback" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("26-07-2017 19:33", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Ja" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("28-07-2017 18:16", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Ingen Kontakt" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("28-07-2017 18:16", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Optaget" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.ParseExact("28-07-2017 18:16", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider), "Optaget" });
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { });

            string[] uniqueStatus = table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Status")).Distinct().Where(x => x != null).ToArray();

            DataTable results = new DataTable();
            results.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            foreach (string status in uniqueStatus)
            {
                results.Columns.Add(status, typeof(int));
            }

            var groups = table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<object>("Date") != null).GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = results.Rows.Add();
                newRow["Date"] = group.Key;
                var colGroups = group.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Status")).ToList();
                foreach (var colGroup in colGroups)
                {
                    if (colGroup.Key.Length > 0)
                    {
                        newRow[colGroup.Key] = colGroup.Count();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran your code just as it was, that gave me just the output I wanted. now I am implenting it to use the data filled from the mysql data adapter. Will update the post when I'm done. Thanks so far

Comment: How can I make this line ignore null text "                string[] uniqueStatus = table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Status")).Distinct().ToArray();
"

Comment: Here is one way : string[] uniqueStatus = table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Status")).Distinct().Where(x => x.Length > 0).ToArray();

Comment: I'm getting a "object refference was not set to an instance of an object". The whole thing seems to fall apart when the table is filled from the mysql data adapter

Comment: Be more specific which line is giving error.  I made a small change that may resolve error, but not sure.

Comment: I updated the question to specify the problem abit more detailed. Thanks

Comment: I updated code to test for null in a couple of locations.

Comment: It's a little wierd, it runs without errors now, but the result table never gets populated?

Comment: Can you post an example that will support the populating I need? As said, the datatable table is filled by a mysql adapter

Comment: The best thing to do is to put a break point (F9) in the code after the table is filled from query. When break point is reached hover mouse over table. There is a down arrow and then click on DataVisualizer. You can then look at the results to help figure out what is wrong

Comment: I figured out that the index I used for definyng the date column was swapped with the status.. Sorry for wasting your time but thanks for making me realize that what the problem